# Javascript String to Float conversion inside string building

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am preparing database insert query in Snowflake Stored Procedure.

My expected output is **2.0**

```js
console.log(`INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.MONITORING (COUNT, MESSAGE) VALUES (` + parseFloat('1.0') + 1 + `, 'DUM')`);

console.log(parseFloat('1.0') + 1);
```

**Output of a 1st Line:**

```
INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.MONITORING (COUNT, MESSAGE) VALUES (11, 'DUM')
```

**Output of a 2nd Line:**

```
2
```

What is happening at a first line and why its returning 11 instead of 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that you are concatenating a string, so if you want to make an addition before the concat, you should use a parenthesis `(parseFloat('1.0') + 1)`. Use the `toFixed()` function to indicate the decimals after comma or dot:

```js
console.log(`INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.MONITORING (COUNT, MESSAGE) VALUES (` + (parseFloat('1.0') + 1).toFixed(1) + `, 'DUM')`);

console.log((parseFloat('1.0') + 1).toFixed(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're converting to float and then immediately concatenating into the string. Instead, you can make use of your [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
`INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.MONITORING (COUNT, MESSAGE) VALUES (${parseFloat('1.0') + 1}, 'DUM')`
```